# Resource.rc Windres Syntax Error (Mingw)

Tags: c++, c, gcc, mingw, windres

I got a project from MS VS, and at the moment I'm migrating it to compile using gcc for Windows.

The C code is completely ported, but I'm having a problem using windres to compile the projet resources.

I'm having a syntax error, reported by windres, at those single lines:

CONTROL         "Tab1",IDC_FILETAB,"SysTabControl32",TCS_BOTTOM,0,1,336,194

CONTROL         "Tab1",IDC_KEYS,"SysTabControl32",TCS_BOTTOM,27,111,73,6

All others use of Control, with similar syntax, works as expected...

According with http://cygwin.com/cygwin-ug-net/windres.html , the follow syntax is used for CONTROL:

CONTROL ["name",] id, class, style, x,y,w,h [,exstyle] [data]

CONTROL ["name",] id, class, style, x,y,w,h, exstyle, helpid [data]

At top of resource.rc I'm including afxres.h,winuser.h and windows.h .

Can any one give me a help? I don't have a clue about what to do....

BTW, if I comment those lines, all ends with no errors, but the executable cannot works properly.

Thanks

Edit: After more search on the internet.. I found that windres already had many problems with syntax accepted on windows resource compiler, mainly because some classes aren't visible for windres. So if any one know an alternative classes/id, or where it are defined to include, I can workaround it.

Comment: And the error message is... ?

Comment: Syntax error on line 100 , after comment it... error on line 174. Just that.... I pasted those line here

Answer (score 0):

You might have copied the code happens all the time just open the code in a textviewer and change the format to plain text or edit and replace characters like " , ' etc.

Comment: It's the same code from VS project. On VS it works perfect, but on windres I got those erros :(